# iPhone - Getting the lock screen background image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, wallpaper

Into my app, I need to display the lock screen background image chosen by the user.
How can I get that image to display it without using private API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to get the lock screen or home screen images.

Comment: hmm... how does it work then http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-screen-weather/id487180806?mt=8?

Comment: Update: I figured. They do nasty trick to keep the app alive by playing a mute sound. Probably should be banned from the store.

Comment: Is that app still on the app store?

Comment: Nope, as far as I can tell :)